# Peculiar headlines

Tags: visual, steganography

The local paper this morning seemed a bit strange.  The whole thing was a bunch or random squares!  Below are some snippets from what should have been headlines of articles.

[image: squares]

Hex values (#XXXXXX) of squares:

```
#AABBEE #DDEEFF #AACCEE #DDAACC #AABB00
#EEDDAA #DDDDEE #DDBBEE #EEFFFF #EEEE00
#DDAADD #FFAACC #EEDDFF #AACCAA #DDEE00
#BBAABB #EEFFEE #DDDDEE #AADDBB #EEEE00
#DDEECC #AADDEE #CCEEDD #EEDDCC #AACCAA
```

Comment: Poor Deus' eyes

Comment: @DavidStarkey Any chance you could transcribe this into text form somehow?

Comment: Agreed with Mike - say, by giving the RGB values? (I could extract them myself, but it'd be tedious.)

Comment: random fact: the image is 300x299, not 300x300. possibly a screenshotting mistake, but possibly relavant...

Comment: @Deus and Mike, I did a quick table, taking the hex values.

Comment: @Beastly looks like hexspeak with lossy compression.

Comment: It looks like Web Colors (not web-safe colors, though), so we can go down to just 3 symbols per square.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Moring Starkey** ($1.5)

Wednesday June 7

> ABE DEFACED A CAB

*Taxi driver Abraham Goldman, protested unfair...*

> ED ADDED BEEF FEE

*A sad day for meat lovers today on the streets of...*

> DAD FACED FACADE

*An exhibition of fences with people's faces is to...*

> BABE FED DEAD BEE

*Everyone's favorite pig has switched to an all insect...*

> DECADE CEDED CACA (i'm  actually not sure about this one)

*Today marks the 10th anniversary of the indepencence...*

Comment: Loved the added article text as well. Nice one!